# match datePicker date and timer with users Date and Time (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, date, if-statement, datepicker

My code below creates a date picker and has it select a date and time. All I want to do is when the date picker's date and time match the user's phone's date and time is to print the line "cool". That's it. I commented the line that is causing me problems.

```
import UIKit

var dateFormatter : DateFormatter!

let datePicker2 = UIDatePicker();
let date = Date()

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let datePicker : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 330,width: self.view.frame.size.width,height: 220))
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.dateAndTime
        self.view.addSubview(datePicker)

        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.change(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

        dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm"
    }

    @IBAction func change(_ sender : UIDatePicker)
    {
        dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
        ///print cool line; what I have does not work
        if dateLabel.text == String(describing: date){
            print("cool")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are `datePicker2` and `date` declared outside of the class instead of inside the class?

Comment: And your date format should be `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"`.

Comment: @rmaddy did not know that datePicker2 and date should be inside of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary issue is how you compare the two dates. You should be using the same date formatter to convert both `Date` instances to strings in the same format. Then you can compare the two strings.

```
@IBAction func change(_ sender : UIDatePicker)
{
    let pickerString = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    let nowString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())

    dateLabel.text = pickerString
    if pickerString == nowString {
        print("cool")
    }
}
```

You are also using the wrong format. You need `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"`. `YYYY` is slightly different. You always want `yyyy` unless you have a clearly understood and specific need to use `YYYY`. And for the hour you want `HH` instead of `hh`. `HH` is a 24-hour hour while `hh` is a 12-hour hour. Only use `hh` is you also use `a` (for AM/PM).

And your properties should be inside the class, not outside.

Move `datePicker2` inside the class.

`date` is now obsolete based on my answer so you can remove it completely.

`dateFormatter` should also be moved inside the class.

Comment: this works if you move the datePicker to the current time. But If you set the datePicker to a time and then when the current time matches the datePicker nothing happens. I am trying to make a alarm so I want to set the datePicker and have it print something when it matches the current date and time.

Comment: That's a completely separate bit of functionality and would require a whole new question. The question you asked above is how to print "cool" when the user changes the picker to the current time. That question has been answered. If you have a whole other question about settings alarms and knowing when the current date/time matches a date/time previously selected by a user, you should post a new question with all relevant details about that issue.