# set alarm using DatePicker (swift3

Tags: if-statement, time, swift3, datepicker, alarm

My code below works that if you manually use to datePicker to match the date and time with the users date and time it will print cool. However the code does not work as a alarm. I can set the date picker ahead of the user time and when the user time matches the date pickers timer nothing prints. I just want to be able to select a date/time using date picker and when the users eventually matches the datePickers time just print cool.

```
import UIKit

 var dateFormatter : DateFormatter!

 let datePicker2 = UIDatePicker();
 let date = Date()

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let datePicker : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 330,width: self.view.frame.size.width,height: 220))
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.dateAndTime
    self.view.addSubview(datePicker)

    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.change(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

    dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm"
}

@IBAction func change(_ sender : UIDatePicker)
{
    let pickerString = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
let nowString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())

dateLabel.text = pickerString
if pickerString == nowString {
    print("cool")
}
}}
```

Comment: FYI - you didn't update your date format as I mentioned in [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45108348/1226963).

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your if statement is only being called when the picker moves.  You need a timer that fires every second looking to see if they match.  To use the method below you just need to move the pickerString and nowString up to global variables.  If you don't like that you can refactor and use as you want.

```
var pickerString: String?
var nowString: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        if pickerString == nowString {
            print("cool")
        }
}
```

#buildSucceeded